# Focus on input text after selecting option from selectbox in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm trying to set focus on input type text after selecting option from selectbox. After selecting option it focus inputs for nano second and then focus again on select box.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srjahir32/7gx1u96L/).

Here is code

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" layout layout-align="center center">
        <md-select ng-model="myModel" placeholder="Pick" ng-change="onChange()" md-on-open="onOpen()">
            <md-option value="0">Zero</md-option>
            <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
        </md-select>

        <input type="text" id="fc">
    </div>
<script>
    angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.onChange = function() {
            document.getElementById('fc').focus();
        };

        $scope.onOpen = function() {
           document.getElementById('fc').focus();
        };
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It seems to be related to the angular material dropdown... I'm not sure what is causing it though. If you use a standard HTML select it works fine. I did notice that this works with the md-select, but it isn't a great practice to use $scope.$watch anymore.

`$scope.$watch('myModel', function() {
         $document[0].getElementById('fc').focus();

    });`

Comment: @sledsworth Yes its angular material. Trying to achieve this with angular material. What's problem with $watch ?

Comment: There isn't a problem per say, but with the release of Angular 1.5 and > it is recommended to use component lifecycle hooks instead of using $watch, from my understanding anyway.

Comment: I tried using $watch, its not working.

Comment: Did you make sure to inject $document and $scope into your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's mentioned in the comments, this is probably an `angular-material` bug, because it's just working fine if we use a standard select instead. *(I think a [github issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues) should be created)*

That said, you can make an uggly workaround to solve it until the bug is fixed: Atttach a directive to manually focus on the input (with a `$timeout`) when the select is changed.

**Directive**: Note the timeout. It needs to be a considerable time... (it works with 250ms):

```
.directive('focus', function($timeout) {
   return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$on(attr.focus, function(e) {
        $timeout(function() {        
          elem[0].focus();         
        }, 250);
      });
   };
})
```

**Controller**: broadcast an event when the select is changed.

```
$scope.onChange = function() {
   $scope.$broadcast('selectChanged');
};
```

**View**: Attach the focus directive to your input element:

```
<input type="text" id="fc" focus="selectChanged">
```

I've forked your jdsfiddle. **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7gx1u96L/4/)** you can see it working.

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried it. its not working. You're right, its bug issue.

Comment: Yes If you check fiddle you updated, is not working at all.

Comment: Hi @user3288891! It's strange...I'm seeing it working well on chrome. Could you try to slightly  increase the timeout (maybe 250 it's not enough for all the cases) and please let me know your thoughts

Comment: Great @user3288891! I know it's an ugly workaround...but at least you have a temporal solution until angular-material bug is fixed. Glad to help